# Overloading global variable in function

Tags: function, global-variables, capl

What is happening with global variable in CAPL, when it is initializing again in function or testfunction?

```
variables
{
    int i;
}

testfunction temp()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    temp();
}
```

Comment: What about pasting this into a CAPL-file and giving it a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Variables** section of CAPL, global variables are declared. Identifiers defined here have program scope. Global variable can be accessed by any function of your entire program after its declaration.

```
variables
{
    int xyz; // Identifier 'xyz' declared in an program scope
}
```

Second identifier is declared in an function scope and is not distinct form previous identifier. Function scope has more inner scope.

```
void temp()
{
    int xyz; // Identifier 'xyz' declared in an function scope 
    xyz=5;
    write("Inner scope -> d%",xyz);
}
```

CAPL has 'C like' scope rules set so: *If two identifiers have the same name but different scope, the identifier in the inner scope **hides** the identifier in the outer scope.*

In this example, the object xyz in function temp hides the global variable xyz:

```
on key * // call event
{
  xyz=10;
  write("Outer Scope -> %d",xyz);  //  Program Scope
  temp();                          //  Function Scope
}
```

Output:

- " Inner Scope -> **5** "
- " Outer Scope -> **10** "